# Jpeg upload - image is currupted, but still visible

Tags: php, image, upload

I have a php image upload form.

the image gets to the server, but then the image ends up looking like this:[image]

That is not a snake at all!  I'm not doing anything special to the image, just uploading and naming it.  The corruption is adding about 100% to the file size.

I am hoping that by seeing the image somebody will have a bright idea as to what is happening.  Thanks!

I am using laravel, but a previous iteration of this question in that context provided no leads, so I am asking in the context of the image alone, to cast a wider net.

---

upload form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'/manage/photos/upload', 'class'=>'form-signin',  'files' => true)) }}   
    {{ Form::file('image') }}
    {{ Form::submit('Upload Photos', array('class'=>'btn btn-large btn-primary btn-block'))}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

file receiving code in my controller:

```
public function uploadPhoto() {
    $file = Input::file('image');
    $input = array('image' => $file);
    $rules = array(
        'image' => 'image'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if ( $validator->fails() )
    {
        return Redirect::to('/manage/photos')->with('message', 'There was a problem:');
    } else {
        $destinationPath = 'profileimages';
        $filename = uniqid('', true).'.jpg';    
        Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'The photo was successfully uploaded');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code of your image upload?

Comment: I'm doing it in larave, but when I asked it in a laravel-ey context there were no leads, so I got it into my head that I should pursue it from the angle of "what does it look like is wrong with this image?".  None the less I will add the code.

Comment: that kind of thing'd happen to some bytes in the middle of the file getting corrupted, or the file being truncated. download this "bad" image and compare it to the original one. look for size differences, and run it through a text editor and look for stuff like php errors/warnings embedding inside.

Comment: cool! just leave it alone and call it art. ;=)

Comment: @MarcB - the files themselves grow by about 100%, I had not though/was afraid to look at the data.

Comment: if the file size is changing, then yeah, you've got a corruption issue. You'll have to look at the files' contents to see what's changing.

Comment: @TrassVasston I have no sense about laravel. But this line looks like you save the image ALWAYS as .jpg **$filename = uniqid('', true).'.jpg';** Maybe you upload a ".png" with transparency(or some other special thing) or a ".gif" and it gets corrupted when you save it as ".jpg" ? You should save it in the same format like it was before.

Comment: @MarcB I'm looking at the files now - they are identical until they are not - can you give me a lead as to what to do now?  the image is a giant string of values similar to "...+\9D\9E\93\E2\BBeH\95\A5\CBc\9C\D7Sk\A9[..."

Comment: @Xatenev I am testing using plain ol' jpegs, and have tried quite a number of them from different sources, all failing in similar fashion

Comment: **Form::file('image', $attributes = array());** can you try replacing this to your form? ( Just a guess, this is what it looks like in the laravel documentation )

Comment: @Xatenev I am fiddling with that now (no dice so far) - can you direct me to the docs you found?  the ones here (http://laravel.com/docs/html) do not show the "attributes" param for the form::file element.

Comment: Yes it does, im in the same documentation, search for this: Generating Other Inputs

echo Form::email($name, $value = null, $attributes = array());
echo Form::file($name, $attributes = array());